# Does anyone know how many square miles/kilometers that Kingdoms of Amalur is including Teeth of Naros and Mithros?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning

I am in a debate with a person about the size of the map of Amalur vs the size of Skyrim, I'm not good with maps, or counting cells, but I was hoping possibly for some sort of height-map for the Amalur map or some proof that it's bigger then Skyrim's map?

I can't prove it on my own, I have knowledge that it's been done in the past (square miles comparison), but all of those "studies" or whatever you call them are no longer on the internet.

I just really wanna know how big the map ACTUALLY is in APPROXIMATE square miles, can some sort of cell expert or math whizz come in here and give me super deep detailed information about how big the map of Kingdom's of Amalur actually is?

For reference:
[image: Here is a picture for you]
Here is Mithros, Mithros is a recent addition to the game, it's right next to the compass on the map, to the left of the first picture, was hard to find as the DLC is relatively new:
[image: Here is a picture for you]
Here's what the player looks like on that map, the yellow arrow:
[image: Here is a picture for you]
Finally, here is the player in the actual world:
[image: Here is a picture for you]
(https://d30xqvs6b65d10.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning-vista.jpg))

Also if this helps, it actually makes the map look smaller but includes ALL areas of the map in one thing and where they are today, but I left it out in case it got confusing:
[image: Here is a picture for you]

Please help, even if Skyrim actually is larger, that's not what matter to me so much, it's just the NOT knowing how big Amalur is. I'm curious about both the size of the actual map, and how much of it is actually playable in terms of those square miles. Based on cells and whatnot, or perhaps a heightmap, please and thank you!

I already know of this list, but would like some evidence from a person who has experience and can figure out on their own how big the game is in square miles: https://www.thegamer.com/video-game-rpg-open-world-smallest-largest-ever/

I don't count that list as concrete evidence because they never cited their source outside of talking to the developers, for Elder Scrolls games and Witcher 3, the sizes were figured out by the players, which is what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.thegamer.com/video-game-rpg-open-world-smallest-largest-ever), the map is 16mi², but I don't think expansions are counted.

Comment: I know, I've checked that, but the problem is they didn't cite their source.

Comment: I noticed you added another tag, and now your question uses both original and remastered version. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I've never used this website before, I made an account specifically to ask this question.

Comment: I'm asking about re-reckoning but I figure more people will see this if I add more tags, since it asks you to add up to 5 tags.

Comment: 5 tags is an upper limit, not a suggestion. We prefer to use only essential tags, there are few questions asked per day :)

Comment: @cheesecheese If you click the link in the article, you can see that the source is an interview they did with the Associate Producer of the game.